# Get value from input several times without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an input and a button. When I clicked the button I want to take the value from input and put it into a variable. How can do this action several times without refreshing the page ?
Example:
Input: John
Button: click
let x = John
-->without refreshing the page
Input: Bob
Button: click
let x = Bob

Comment: Why was ajax added as tag?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable to store the value of the input and a function that is being called when the button is clicked. `name` in this example holds the value of the input and is updated everytime the button is clicked.

```js
let name;
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<input id="name" />
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```